Shortcut for newtcblisting and tcolorbox
I tried to create some shortcuts using \def and \newcommand, but it show an error File ended while scanning use of \next..
I don't know if it is possible to do that if the shortcut involve \begin and \end, and \newtcblisting.
What I want to solve is for example ,to type \bmybox{Title} to replace \begin{mybox}{Title}.
My Codes:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#2,#1}

%the lines with error (begin)
\def\bmybox{\begin{mybox}}
    \def\emybox{\end{mybox}}
%\newcommand\bmybox[2]{\begin{mybox}}
%\newcommand\emybox{\end{mybox}}
%the lines with error (end)
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{mybox}[listing only]{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{mybox}[listing side text]{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
    
%the lines with error (begin)
\bmybox{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
\emybox
%the lines with error (end)
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Why would you want to type \bmybox{Title}...\emybox instead of \begin{mybox}{Title}...\end{mybox}?

By the way, you should not use $$ for math display, use \[...\] instead.

@jlab I want to find a way so that I can type less code (which is not the main code) in the whole document

@TimLam a nice editor should be able to relief you of much of the coding stress without compromising code quality. Many LaTeX editors support some shortcuts for environments.

for the listing environments, you have to set things up specially as collecting verbatim material requires a way to signal the end of that material. tcolorbox is wrapping listings which makes this easy and hides the difficulties. but you would have to set up similar machinery for the sole purpose of making your code more opaque. also, if you use a proper editor, you will not have any of the nice things in provides out-of-the-box e.g. completion, syntax highlighting, exemption from spellcheck.

@cfr I am using TexStudio and Vscode for this. But I am looking for a more general technique that help. For example, this uses some box that require some complicated parameters. So I tried to used a meaningful shortcut latex command that help to overcome this difficulty.

@TimLam Better use an environment instead of a macro for fragile content like source code.

as you see for verbatim-style enviornments you can not hide the end code but for all enviornemnts it is usually a bad idea to hide the environment syntax  behind commands, that is a core feature of latex syntax and hiding it will confuse other readers of the code, editor syntax highlighters, and given a reasonable tex editorr means you have to type more.  most editors will let you add `\begin{foo]  \end{foo} in a few keystrokes (just one or two for standard environemnts) but your custom commands would probably have to be typed out in full

Thanks you for all your advices! I see the advantages of not doing this now.

I cannot recommend this, but as long as you don't intend to nest \bmybox..\emybox you can have \bmybox switch to verbatim-catcode-régime, gather an argument that is delimited by \emybox tokenized in verbatim catcode-régime and pass that argument to \scantokens, nested between \begin{mybox}..\end{mybox}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#2,#1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bmybox{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \do\^^I\do\^^M\do\e\do\m\do\y\do\b\do\o\do\x\dospecials
  \innerbmybox
}%
\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\innerbmybox{vvv}{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\innerbmybox{%
    \def\innerbmybox##1#2{%
       \endgroup\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\scantokens{#3##1#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\innerbmybox|\end{mybox}||\emybox||\endgroup\begin{mybox}|%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
    
    \begin{mybox}[listing only]{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
   
    \begin{mybox}[listing side text]{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
    \end{mybox}
    
\bmybox{Title}
        $$y=x^2$$
\emybox
\end{document}


Thats fine. I have tested it. It is perfect to me and it is exactly what I want and that helps me to apply to different situations.
